What is an anti-vortex?
May be it's a stupid question, since the concept of anti-vortex should be as old as vortex itself. But strangely I found no proper definition or mathematical explanation of anti-vortex, neither in any fluid mechanics text book nor over the internet. Even a search for this word in books' pdfs gave nothing.
I know that vortex and anti-vortex pairs gets annihilated on merging. I also saw some arrowed sketches but I still cannot get what's "anti" about it (except the annihilation part).
Do they always form in pairs?
If opening of bathtub drain creates vortex, then what creates anti-vortex?
There are some answers here that are from the perspective of magnets. But I want to know from fluid perspective. Or colloids in a fluid to be more precise.

Anti-vortex is a short-hand name for a vortex that has an opposite vorticity vis-a-vis another vortex that was discussed earlier.
Coming to the source of vortices, strictly speaking, it is not the bathtub drain that creates vortices (bathtub drain preserves mirror and/or time reversal symmetry), but the rotation of Earth: the water vortices famously rotate counter-clockwise in southern hemisphere.
